# iPhone - how may I hide a view and let it's space be used by other view (like android visibility = GONE)

Tags: iphone, animation, uiview, visibility, show-hide

Do you know a simple (or not simple) way to hide a view (or anything like a view) and let the other views of the screen use the place left blank ? And make the opposite when showing back that view. Something like Android Visibility = GONE for layers.

As far as I know, using setHidden=YES only hide the view from the screen but does not rearrange anything around it.

On Android, there are 2 hidding method. One like visibility = HIDE, and the other : visibility = GONE.

Let's say we have 3 views each with an height of 100px.
On Android :
If you set view2 visibility = HIDE, it just hides, and nothing else happens.
If you set view2 visibilty = GONE, the view2 hides from the screen and the view3 automaticaly takes the place freed by view2.

That's what I'm looking to on the iPhone.
I imagine there no auto way to do this but do you know any snippet or code making this possible ?

Thank you

Comment: Hi, my problem is also the same.The difference is that, that I want this with iPad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no auto-tiling in iOS, so the only way to do this is to resize each of the views to how you want them to be yourself, perhaps by implementing `layoutSubviews` on their superview.

Comment: don't you know any snippets anywhere ?