# Hide view in iOS and rearrange the other views?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I've 10 `UITextField` on `UIView` and a `UIPickerView`. the number of text fields will change according to row selection of picker.we can use view.hidden = YES for hide the view but it left the space(i want other text fields fill the blank space by rearrange their position).
I think one way to do so is hide the view and set frame of others, but it will very complex to handle in my case. So is there any way like Visibility = GONE for layers in Android.or any other suggestion other than to set frame?

**Edit:** I know there is no built in functionality in iOS.Any idea about how to achieve this?

**Edit:** My question is that when we hide a view(UITextField) is there any way that others views(other UITextField and UIButton or any view) can be repositioned to cover the blank caused by hide a view?

Comment: down voter can you please explain what is wrong with this question?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question can you provide more detail or make it more clear please.

Comment: That makes more sense. Thanks

Comment: I've edited question please have a look.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4741985/iphone-how-may-i-hide-a-view-and-let-its-space-be-used-by-other-view-like-an

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no any built in functionality, but u can simplify setting frame by maintaining Y value of your subviews, means if you want to display the view set Y value to it's frame and increase that value for next view, and set increased Y value to next view to be displayed If u want to hide view don't set it to that particular view, keep it for next view u want to display.

Comment: if this is the only way then it will be horrible for me.